# Почему из таблицы не удаляет строки вставленые при помощи jquery?

Tags: jquery, table

**Существует** таблица на bootstrap...

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">№</th>
        <th scope="col">Фімилія</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Імя</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="table-teachers">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <th>Петров</th>
        <th>Иван</th>
        <th>
          <button class="btn btn-danger row-delete" title="видалити">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </th>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Далее есть jquery код который удаляет и добавляет строки в таблице...

*Удаляет:*

```
$('.row-delete').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

*Добавляет:*

```
$('.row-add').click(function(){
   var table_row = '<tr>                                                                                                            
      <th scope="row">0</th>                                                                                        
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="" value=""></td>                                            
      <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="" value=""></td>                                                                                    
      <td>
         <button class="btn btn-danger row-delete" title="видалити">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </button>
      </td>                                                                                 
   </tr>';
   $('.table-teachers').append(table_row);
});
```

**Проблема** состоит в том что те строки которые добавлены через jquery не удаляются. А те которые подгрузились при старте документа - удаляются.

**Пробовал** также

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

думая что может из-за этого не хочет удалять добавленые строки, но нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте делегирование. В общем случае самом примитвном надо писать так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.row-delete', function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

и

```
$(document).on('click', '.row-add', function(){
```

А в частном случае вместо `document` должен быть написан селектор родителя, который НИКОГДА не меняется. То есть как загрузился и **его самого** ничем не заменяют (но внутри него могут менять). То есть в вашем случае это возможно будет вот так:

```
$('.table').on('click', '.row-add', function(){
```

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: На здоровье.)))

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что **`document`** ничего не знает об элементах добавленных динамически. Он ведь парсил **`DOM`** тогда, когда их ещё не было. А для перехвата события по новым элементам необходимо "дёрнуть" `document` снова. Это делается через функцию **`on();`**

```
$('.row-delete').on('click', '.row-delete', function() {

    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

В таком виде событие **`click`** снова обходит набор элементов, таким образом в него попадают и новые динамически созданные элементы.